# Load new View Controller from View Controller added as a subview

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, pagination

Hi I'm using the following library in my project https://github.com/firebaseco/FireUIPagedScrollView I've added a few view controllers as pages. My issue now is that when a user selects a button on one of my view controllers loaded as a page the page is simply replaced with my new view controller rather than the view controller holding the pages. Any one know how I can move to a completely new view controller when something is pressed on one of the pages?

The code I'm using to load my other view pager from the page is below

```
    WebViewController *dvController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    dvController.url = url;
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dvController];
    nc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution ended up being create a property in the page and set it in the ViewController that has pages added to it

In Page.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController;
```

In the Page Holding View Controller set the property equal to the holders navigationController

```
Page  *pageVC = [[Page alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page" bundle:nil];
pageVC.navController = self.navigationController;
```

Then in Page.m when I wanted to push a new View Controller simply used the now set property when pushing the new View Controller

```
@synthesize navController
...
NewViewController *dvController = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navController pushViewController:dvController animated:NO];
```